# Prove the set $A := \{\bar{x} \in V | \langle\bar{x}, \bar{v}\rangle \geq c \}$ is connected in $(V, d)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\langle\,,\rangle$ an inner product over $V$. Let $d$ be the metric induced by $\langle\,,\rangle$.

Prove that the set $A := \{\bar{x} \in V | \langle\bar{x}, \bar{v}\rangle \geq c \}$ is connected in $(V, d)$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\bar{0} \neq \bar{v} \in V$.

I thought of using the union theorem somehow (splitting $A$ into a set of connected subsets that have a non-empty intersection), but, drawing the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case for inspiration, there doesn't seem to be a natural way to accomplish this.

I also thought of proving it is path-connected, but, again looking at $\mathbb{R}^2$, I'm not certain how this could be accomplished.

Finding a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $A$ that utilises $d$ somehow also doesn't seem relevant.

I must be missing something... would be helpful to hear others' thoughts/suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Any _convex_ set is obviously path-connected\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path-connectedness is quite easy: Just use
$$
t \mapsto tv_1 + (1-t)v_2,
$$
and use
$$
\langle tv_1 + (1-t)v_2, x \rangle = t \langle v_1, x \rangle + (1 - t) \langle v_2, x \rangle \ge tc + (1 - t)c = c.
$$

Comment: Indeed simple. I was stuck on looking for something to use $d$ since it got such a focus in the question, but I guess it was just a red herring of sorts...